# How to click button in a browser using ID programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, automation, autohotkey

I am a freelancer, I have to upload images on a website, and I need automation. Taking example of this website, in google chrome, I can open console and enter

```
$('#wmd-image-button').click()
```

And this will open popup-up to insert image.

I was using Internet explorer with autohotkey, using `"DOM"`, here is the problem: I cannot run internal functions like `"CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(4,this);"`,

I can only use functions like `wb.document.getElementById("cke_8").Click()`, but on their website, the button is triggered with mousedown, and nothing happens with `click()`.

IE is not letting me trigger `mousedown()` and I am stuck at this part! Should I try to learn to build chrome extension for this? OR is there a way to trigger internal javascript functions using AHK in IE? Or Is there a completely different "correct" way to press the "image upload" button programmatically?

PS: If there is something wrong with this question, please comment before downvoting!

Comment: There are a few ways you could automate this. You could use pyautogui and script out the mouse clicks or you could use the requests lib with python or use selenium
there are lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotkey provides more of an external capability to the browser vs. easy access to the internal content and functions of a page loaded within the browser.

Are you stuck with IE and Chrome?  Can you use Firefox and possibly the GreaseMonkey add-on to automate this?

Comment: its an old question, I should have replied to myself. This button is actually imageupload button on ckeditor. I tried to trigger this button in chrome, firefox etc. The button only triggers when I manually click it, but does not get triggered by javascript (probably due to security reasons).  But element.focus() worked. So now I use autohotkey to send {enter} key when focus is on the button. Does not always work, but it gets my job done most of the time :)